# Is there any indication that New Olympians can be related to the Third Race?

Tags: character, gargoyles

In *Gargoyles* all the Egyptian and Norse Gods who appeared came out to be Children of Oberon/Third Race. But what about Olympians?

Is there any canon indication about it in any of the episode or in extended canon? Or out of universe hint? As New Olympians was one of the proposed spin-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least out of universe.

According to series creator Greg Weisman,

> I said the New Olympians were Children of Oberon/Mortal hybrids.

Other questions and answers on the archive page clarify that they are specifically "Children of Mab."

In response to a question about why the New Olympians did not appear at the Gathering:

> I think the New Olympians and the Children of Mab had a falling out long ago.

Source: [Ask Greg Archives](https://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/archives.php?lid=9)